# Build Enumeration Path from Adjacency List in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, hierarchy, adjacency-list

### Initial scenario

My software uses a tree data structure, and I store it in SQL. I use the abstraction called **Adjacency List** which consists of each row storing `ID` and `ParentID`.

`ID` is *Primary Key* and `ParentID` is a *Foreign Key* to the same table.

### The problem

I want to  "convert" my SQL abstraction to **Path Enumeration**. It consists of each row storing `ID` and a `varchar` field storing the path of the IDs, from the root to the current row. For example, the `Path` field of the row with `ID = 6` in this tree:

[image: Tree]

Would be `/1/2/4/6/`. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database), by the name *Lineage Column*.

### Question

How do I build a column `Path` from an existing database that only has `ID` and `ParentID`?

Comment: I strongly recommend against this.  Combining multiple values into a single field is a strong sql-anti-pattern.  Without knowing your needs I couldn't be certain, but perhaps converting your adjacency-list to a closure-table or nested-sets would be more useful to you?  Neither of which breach the atomicity of a relational data structure.  *(Also, we'd need to know which RDBMS you're using.  Some support recursion, some do it in 'unique' ways, some don't at all.)*

Comment: @MatBailie, we just need the to retrieve an object and its descendants, and we only delete entire subtrees. I also prefer the _Closure Table_ abstraction, but I was a lost vote! ;)

Comment: @LucasReid - As described you're getting an object and its (Asc)endents rather that its (Desc)endents.  Also, we still need to know the RDBMS.

Comment: I'll try to convince my team once again to use the Closure Tables. I'll leave this answer here just for curiosity purposes.

Comment: Adding a `depth` field to each row in the closure table also allows for retrieving the path in-order if that is necessary.

Comment: It's worth noting that this problem also pertains to developers looking to convert an adjacency list to a materialized path. This should be obvious, but I'm pointing it out for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2005 onwards should support the following:

```
WITH
  recursed_tree AS
(
  SELECT
    IDObject,
    concat('/', cast(IDObject as varchar(100)))   AS Path
  FROM
    tbObject
  WHERE
    ParentID IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    next.IDObject,
    concat(prev.Path, '/', cast(next.IDObject as varchar(100)))   AS Path
  FROM
    recursed_tree   AS prev
  INNER JOIN
    tbObject        AS next
       ON prev.IDObject = next.ParentID
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  recursed_tree
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this SQL Server query:

[ `tbObjectHierarchy` has a FK and PK called `IDObject` and a `varchar` called `Path` ]

```
declare @T  as table (IDObject int, Path varchar(500))
declare @T2 as table (IDObject int, Path varchar(500))

insert into tbObjectHierarchy(IDObject, Path)
select o.IDObject, concat('/', cast(o.IDObject as varchar(100)), '/') as Path
from tbObject as o 
where o.ParentID is null

insert into @T (IDObject, Path)
select o.IDObject, concat(h.Path, cast(o.IDObject as varchar(100)), '/') as Path
from tbObject as o
inner join tbObjectHierarchy as h
on o.ParentID = h.IDObject

while exists (select top 1 * from @T)
begin
    insert into tbObjectHierarchy (IDObject, Path)
    select t.IDObject, t.Path
    from @T as t

    delete from @T2

    insert into @T2
    select o.IDObject, concat(t.Path, cast(o.IDObject as varchar(100)), '/') as Path
    from tbObject as o
    inner join @T as t
    on o.ParentID = t.IDObject

    delete from @T

    insert into @T
    select * from @T2
end
```

Comment: This is clearly TSQL then.  Is it version 2005 onwards?  Using a recursive CTE would likely be much simpler and quicker.